# how to std::variant<unsigned long, size_t, unsigned int>

Tags: c++, enable-if

I ran into a portability issue, which is due to the fact that `size_t` varies between platforms (sometimes it is equiv to `unsigned int`, sometimes to `unsigned long`)

What I would like to write is:

```cpp
"if constexpr" / "enable_if" / "whatever"  (size_t == unsigned long)
  using V = std::variant<unsigned int, size_t>;
else
  using V = std::variant<unsigned long, size_t>;
```

What is the less ugly way to write it?

Links to compiler explorer snippet:

https://godbolt.org/z/AZVFEz : using gcc 9.2 64 bits where `size_t` <-> `unsigned long`

https://godbolt.org/z/wWeCbW : using msvc 19.22 32 bits where `size_t` <-> `unsigned int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a conditional type alias, you may use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

```
using V = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<std::size_t, unsigned long>,
            std::variant<unsigned int, size_t>,
            std::variant<unsigned long, size_t>
          >;
```

Comment: Thanks! I really wished "if constexpr" would, have been able to handle it. I guess I need to add "std::conditional" to my collection of awkward "ifs" (together with enable_if and #ifdef)  :-)